# Creating dataset with R with normal distribution

Tags: r, dataset

I was really hoping if you guys could help me with this question.
I am trying to Create a dataset with 2500 random numbers between (0, 1000) using a normal distribution with mean µ and variance σ2 where µ = 65 and σ2= 10+(6+5) = 21 (therefore SD = sqrt(21)=4.58);

Currently I have tried using :

```
  N = 2500
  M = 1
  A = matrix(pnorm(1000, mean=65, sd=4.58, lower.tail=TRUE),N,M)
```

But this doesn't work seem to work. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: `n <- rnorm(2500, mean=65, sd=4.58); hist(n)`?

Comment: try: rnorm(2500, mean=65, sd=4.58) - pnorm expects a vector, not a number of samples

Comment: Thank you LukeA for your quick response but I was just wondering if this is generating numbers from the range 0 to 1000.

Comment: try this `n <- rnorm(2500, mean=500, sd=500/qnorm(1-1e-4)); hist(n)`

Comment: I've tried plotting it but it seems to generate numbers from 0 100 for n in the histogram plot. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you are limiting the numbers to a certain range, then it is not a Normal distribution. However the probability of getting numbers outside that range with the distribution specified is astronomically small (<10^-45).